# Arel (Rails) Is it possible to make complex query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I need to create query to DB with using `ANY/ALL`. After research Arel possibilities I found out that Arel doesn't have any short commands for that (like `eq`, `lt`, `gt` etc) but it has `Arel::SqlLiteral` with only one example. For me it not so obviousl how I can use the classic query like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator ALL
(SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition);
```

instead of the query in the example. Could someone show me how it should look like?

Comment: Hmm.. No ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it with ActiveRecord methods, without usage of Arel:

```
sub_query = Model.select(:column_name).where(condition).to_sql
Model.
  select("column_name(s)").
  where("column_name operator ALL (#{sub_query})")
```